# Try to write own c# - Group by in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

i know about c# - Group by in LINQ. But i want to write groupBy method myself.
i assume, list is given in sorted order below.

```
List<ClassRoomAllocation> classRoomAllocationList = new List<ClassRoomAllocation>();
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{CourseCode = "101", CourseName = "course1", ScheduleInfo = "class1ScheduleInfo"});
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{CourseCode = "101", CourseName = "course1", ScheduleInfo = "class1ScheduleInfo"});
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{CourseCode = "102", CourseName = "course2", ScheduleInfo = "class2ScheduleInfo"});
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{CourseCode = "102", CourseName = "course2", ScheduleInfo = "class2ScheduleInfo"});
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{CourseCode = "102", CourseName = "course2", ScheduleInfo = "class2ScheduleInfo"});
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{CourseCode = "103", CourseName = "course3", ScheduleInfo = "class3ScheduleInfo"});
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{CourseCode = "103", CourseName = "course3", ScheduleInfo = "class3ScheduleInfo"});
```

i want to group based on course Code.
result will be like this.

```
 1. 101,  CourseName = "course1", ScheduleInfo = "class1ScheduleInfo"  +"class1ScheduleInfo"
 2. 102, CourseName = "course2", ScheduleInfo = "class2ScheduleInfo" + "class2ScheduleInfo" + "class2ScheduleInfo"
 3. 103, CourseName = course3, ScheduleInfo = "class3ScheduleInfo" + "class3ScheduleInfo"
```

how can i write my own groupBy method ? i thought it can be done by following approch. But i can not grouping.

```
List<List<ClassRoomAllocation>> classRoomAllocationGroups = new List<List<ClassRoomAllocation>>();
```

Comment: if you want to write your own then start it? do you want others to write for you completely?

Comment: You can't create just List of Lists, since an `IGrouping` has also a `Key` besides of a containing `List`. Now if there was some kind of variable that could contain a `Key` and `Value` pairs... Or better yet, something that enforces the `Key` to be a unique value...

Comment: What kind of problem you want to solve with that? Getting a List<List<ClassRoomAllocation>>?

Comment: mr. Lei Yang. i just want pseudo Code Not whole code. I tried but could not figure it out. i do not want others to write it completely just want hints.

Comment: Exactly what restrictions do you have? You can use any other functions other than GroupBy?

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq `GroupBy`:

```
List<List<ClassRoomAllocation>> classRoomAllocationGroups = classRoomAllocationList.GroupBy(x => x.CourseName).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the grouping code, this may help you

```
    var result = from classRoomAllocation in classRoomAllocationList
                 group classRoomAllocation by classRoomAllocation.CourseCode into classRoomAllocationfGroup
                 select new { CourseCode = classRoomAllocationfGroup.Key,CourseName = classRoomAllocationfGroup.First().CourseName, ScheduleInfo  = classRoomAllocationfGroup.Select(z=>z.ScheduleInfo).Aggregate((current, next) => current + " + " + next)};
```

I have posted a working exmple code for you [here](http://rextester.com/VVSC8394)

Answer (score 0):

I tried and got answer. It is not best but created by me.

```
List<ClassRoomAllocation> classRoomAllocationList = new List<ClassRoomAllocation>();
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{Id = 1, CourseCode = "101", CourseName = "course1", ScheduleInfo = "class1ScheduleInfo"});
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{Id = 2, CourseCode = "101", CourseName = "course1", ScheduleInfo = "class1ScheduleInfo"});
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{Id = 3, CourseCode = "102", CourseName = "course2", ScheduleInfo = "class2ScheduleInfo"});
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{Id = 4, CourseCode = "102", CourseName = "course2", ScheduleInfo = "class2ScheduleInfo"});
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{Id = 5, CourseCode = "102", CourseName = "course2", ScheduleInfo = "class2ScheduleInfo"});
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{Id = 6, CourseCode = "103", CourseName = "course3", ScheduleInfo = "class3ScheduleInfo"});
        classRoomAllocationList.Add(new ClassRoomAllocation{Id = 7, CourseCode = "103", CourseName = "course3", ScheduleInfo = "class3ScheduleInfo"});


        Dictionary<int, List<ClassRoomAllocation>> classRoomAllocationGroups = new Dictionary<int, List<ClassRoomAllocation>>();
        List<ClassRoomAllocation> newClassRoomAllocations = new List<ClassRoomAllocation>();
        newClassRoomAllocations.Add(classRoomAllocationList[0]);
        classRoomAllocationGroups.Add(0, newClassRoomAllocations);

        int j = 0; 
        for (int i = 1; i < classRoomAllocationList.Count; i++)
        {

            if (classRoomAllocationList[i].CourseCode == classRoomAllocationList[i - 1].CourseCode)
            {
                classRoomAllocationGroups[j].Add(classRoomAllocationList[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
                List<ClassRoomAllocation> newClassRoomAllocations2 = new List<ClassRoomAllocation>();
                newClassRoomAllocations2.Add(classRoomAllocationList[i]);
                classRoomAllocationGroups.Add(j, newClassRoomAllocations2);

            }
        }

        List<ClassRoomAllocation> displayClassRoomAllocation = new List<ClassRoomAllocation>();

        foreach (var aClassRoomAllocationGroup in classRoomAllocationGroups)
        {
            ClassRoomAllocation aClassRoomAllocation = new ClassRoomAllocation();
            foreach (var currentClassRoomAllocation in aClassRoomAllocationGroup.Value)
            {
                aClassRoomAllocation.CourseCode = currentClassRoomAllocation.CourseCode;
                aClassRoomAllocation.CourseName = currentClassRoomAllocation.CourseName;
                aClassRoomAllocation.ScheduleInfo = aClassRoomAllocation.ScheduleInfo + " " +
                                                    currentClassRoomAllocation.ScheduleInfo;
            }
            displayClassRoomAllocation.Add(aClassRoomAllocation);
        }

        foreach (ClassRoomAllocation classRoomAllocation in displayClassRoomAllocation)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(classRoomAllocation.CourseCode + " " +classRoomAllocation.CourseName + " " + classRoomAllocation.ScheduleInfo);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I cannot imagine a situation where you want to rewrite linq's Group By, but here is a very simple solution:

```
    public static IDictionary<string, List<ClassRoomAllocation>> GroupBy(List<ClassRoomAllocation> classRoomAllocationList)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, List<ClassRoomAllocation>>();

        foreach (var allocation in classRoomAllocationList)
        {
            var group = result.ContainsKey(allocation.CourseCode)
                ? result[allocation.CourseCode]
                : new List<ClassRoomAllocation>();

            group.Add(allocation);

            result[allocation.CourseCode] = group;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Usage:

```
        var result = GroupBy(classRoomAllocationList);

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            var schedule = String.Join(" + ", item.Value.Select(v => $"\"{v.ScheduleInfo}\""));
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}, CourseName = \"{item.Value.First().CourseName}\", ScheduleInfo = {schedule}");
        }
```